# PHP - utf8_decode() to wrong character

Tags: php, utf8-decode

Trying to use the Twitter search API. When I call `utf8_decode` on a re-tweeted tweet I get speech marks/quotes appear as question marks...

Code:

```
$output .= '
        <div class="leftcoltweet">
            <div class="timg">
                <a href="' . $account . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $image .'"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ttweet">
                ' . utf8_decode($tweet) . '
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="ttime">' . $time . '</div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
    ';
```

Output:

```
RT @IVAOAERO: ?@FilipJonckers: We are aware of and working on a fix for the ATIS issue introduced after last nights network upgrade http://t.co/6FODzr0Y?
```

All other symbols display correctly.

Do I have to set a language to use? If you want to know the atom query I make or anything else then let me know.

Comment: Please can you provide some an example of some code that can be run by people trying to help answer the question? It's important to understand how the twitter data is getting there.

Comment: Unicode to ISO 8859-1 is a lossy conversion as ISO 8859-1 does only contain a tiny part of Unicode (i. e. first 256 characters). What you see is the result of such a lossy conversion. Why don’t you use UTF-8, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

note that `utf8_decode()` works **ONLY** with iso-8859-1 (latin) encoded string.
if you know the character set of the string, you can call:

```
echo iconv("THE_CHARSET","utf8",$tweet);
```