# &nbsp; gives me � on Wordpress content and breaks my Json Data

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

When I use enter in Visual editor on Wordpress, that add `&nbsp;` in Text editor, and when I publish the post, the `&nbsp;` gives this html code :

```
<p>�</p>
```

I think it's a encoded problem ?

With this character my JSON Data content becomes `null` so I really need to fix that.

I thought about use `utf8_decode()` but how can I use it ?

I've tried this code, but that doesn't work :

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Erase "�" */
function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('�', '&nbsp;',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content')
?>
```

Maybe I need to use `utf8_decode()` in this code ? I don't know how to make this...

The website has this html :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Maybe it's the problem ? `charset = utf-8` twice...

Comment: follow this link hope it will work for you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10864084/1491335

Comment: @SamiullahKaifi thanks for reply ! So in my case I've to use : echo iconv("�","utf8",$content); ?

Comment: @SamiullahKaifi Please give me help, I know you can help me ... :(

Comment: What charset are you using in your database? You can check your current character set using a MySQL command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-database-table-column-is-in-mysql

Comment: @Vernon I don't have access to DB :/

Comment: You can check wp-config.php for DB credentials. And download PhpMyAdmin to your server and login using the DB credentials.

Comment: @Vernon firstly, the DB is in utf8 : define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');